# Unable to use Memcached in PHP Fat free framework

Tags: php, caching, memcached, fat-free-framework

I have been trying to implement memcached in my application built in fat free framework. I have read that it should be explicitly defined as "memcached=192.168.--.---:11211" but no matter how I implement it, it uses "folder=tmp/cache/"

**Tried and failed approaches**

1. *config.ini*  
   CACHE="memcached=192.168.--.---:11211"

   *index.php*
   $f3->config('config/config.ini');
   $f3->run();

   *code* 
   $cache = \Cache::instance(); 
   var_dump($cache);

   *Output*
   Object(Cache)#7 (3) { 
    ["dsn":protected] => string(17)"folder=tmp/cache/" 
    ["prefix":protected] => string(12)"randomString" 
    ["ref":protected] => NULL
   }
2. *code*
   $cache = \Cache::instance();
   $cache->load("memcached=192.168.--.---:11211");
   var_dump($cache);

   *Output*
   Object(Cache)#7 (3) { 
    ["dsn":protected] => string(17)"folder=tmp/cache/" 
    ["prefix":protected] => string(12)"randomString" 
    ["ref":protected] => NULL
   }
3. *code*
   $cache = new Cache("memcached=192.168.--.---:11211");
   var_dump($cache);

   *Output*
   Object(Cache)#7 (3) { 
       ["dsn":protected] => string(17)"folder=tmp/cache/" 
       ["prefix":protected] => string(12)"randomString" 
       ["ref":protected] => NULL
   }
4. *index.php*
   $f3->config('config/config.ini');
   $f3->set('CACHE',"memcached=192.168.--.---:11211");
   var_dump($f3->get('CACHE'));

   *Output*
   string(17)"folder=tmp/cache/"

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have installed the proper php extension? Or is the connection secured? Because when there’s an error, the cache engine will just fall back to folder mode.

Comment: I was using memcached in another PHP project and this code snippet was working:

           **$memcache = new \Memcached();
            $memcache->addServer('192.168.--.---', 11211);
            $storageKey = 'STORAGE_KEY_NAME';
            $result2 = $memcache->get($storageKey);
            if ($result2) {
                print_r($result2);
            }else{
             //do smth
            }**


After I read your comment, I realised my mistake. I am using another php (with zts) for this f3 application. Turns out it was the extension issue, now fixed it. Thank you.